# Unable to click on span, and no error is thrown

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on this "dealerships" span, but nothing happens. No error, nothing.

```
<div
      class="x-container x-container-default x-box-layout-ct"
      id="container-1022"
    >
      <div
        id="container-1022-innerCt"
        class="x-box-inner"
        role="presentation"
        style="width: 942px; height: 40px"
      >
        <div id="container-1022-targetEl" class="x-box-target" style="width: 942px">
          <div
            class="x-component toggle-option-plain x-box-item x-component-default inline-select"
            style="margin: 0px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px"
            id="xt_common_dealer_selector_inline_select-1023"
            tabindex="-1"
          >
            <span class="select-option x-item-selected">Dealerships</span
            ><span class="select-option">Companies</span>
```

Things i've tried:

- hovering the element before clicking
- hovering and clicking the parent div
- hovering and clicking the outermost parent div
- waits (implicit, EC.presence_of_element_located)
- selecting the immediate, outermost parent, and the span itself using css
  selects, and xpaths

Here's my code:

```
 driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="xt_common_dealer_selector_inline_select-1023"]/span[2]').click()
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#xt_common_dealer_selector_inline_select-1023 > span:nth-child(2)')
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#xt_common_dealer_selector_inline_select-1023 > span:nth-child(2)').click()
```

Comment: Are you able to share a link to the page you're trying to automate? It would help to be able to play around with it.

Comment: it's a thing for work, so I really can't unfortunately

Comment: first you could check `driver.page_source` to see whan HTML you get. Next you could check if element is not in `<iframe>` because it would need to use `driver.switch_to.frame()`

Comment: What is the error do you see when you use this line `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Dealerships']").click()`, you may want to put some additional delay before this command.